# PowerShell command not executed?

Tags: powershell-2.0, sql-server-data-tools, dacpac, sqlpackage

In the following PowerShell v2.0 script, the command & is not executed :

```
$SqlPackageExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe"
Write-Host "Before SqlPackage"
& "$SqlPackageExe" /Action:Publish $SqlPackageParameters
Write-Host "After SqlPackage"
```

On the console output, I see :
Before SqlPackage
After SqlPackage

I have no error, no log, nothing of the SqlPackage.exe. What's happen ?
My command "& "$SqlPackageExe" /Action:Publish $SqlPackageParameters" works a first time, a second time (database is deployed), and then stops working.
If I close the PowerShell session and open a new PowerShell session, the command works several times, then stops working.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31351075/9976 has a script that logs output - will help you debug.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redirect StdError and StdOut, see the answer that discusses " -RedirectStandardError -RedirectStandardOutput":

[Powershell: Capture program stdout and stderr to separate variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222088/powershell-capture-program-stdout-and-stderr-to-seperate-variables)

Comment: Ok. I could get an error number. It's a known bug in PowerShell when there are too many Console.Write() : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2701373

Thank you for your help.